# How to implement appium's new feature of mobile:getContexts for android hybrid automation

Tags: mobile, automation, android-webview, appium, appium-android

Appium introduced a feature to collect details of webview using mobile command `mobile:getContexts`. Using this feature i want to rule out the detached window from the webview so i can switch to the actual needed window. How do i do that in java? how do i filter the response of `driver.executeScript("mobile:getContexts")` and validate the value of key `attached`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below approach for the latest appium v1.22+,

```
//getContext
String currentContext = (String) appiumDriver.execute(DriverCommand.GET_CURRENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE).getValue();
System.out.println("getContext:"+currentContext);

//SwithToContext (NATIVE_APP)
appiumDriver.execute(DriverCommand.SWITCH_TO_CONTEXT, ImmutableMap.of("name", "NATIVE_APP"));

//SwithToContext (WEBVIEW)
appiumDriver.execute(DriverCommand.SWITCH_TO_CONTEXT, ImmutableMap.of("name", "WEBVIEW"));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).